# Is it possible to read ORC file to Spark Data Frame in sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr, sparklyr, orc

I know that sparklyr has the following read file methods:

- `spark_read_csv`
- `spark_read_parquet`
- `spark_read_json`

What about reading orc files? Is it supported yet by this library?

I know I can use [read.orc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/R/read.orc.html) in SparkR or [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955469/r-read-orc-file-from-s3), but I'd like to keep my code in sparklyr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use low level Spark API in the same way I described in my answer to [Transfer data from database to Spark using sparklyr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41966814/6910411):

```
library(dplyr)
library(sparklyr)

sc <- spark_connect(...)

spark_session(sc) %>% 
  invoke("read") %>% 
  invoke("format", "orc") %>%
  invoke("load", path) %>% 
  invoke("createOrReplaceTempView", name)

df <- tbl(sc, name)
```

where `name` is an arbitrary name used to identify the table

In the current `sparklyr` version you should be able to replace above with `spark_read_source`:

```
spark_read_source(sc, name, source = "orc", options = list(path = path))
```